# Python Pivot Column not recognized

Tags: python, pivot-table

bare in mind I am just starting with Python!

I have 2 CSV files that have the same information but one is 2015 data and the other 2016 (but same columns).
I ran the following code and it gives me exactly what I wanted:
pivot_2016_barri = data_2016.pivot_table(index= ['Nom_Barri'], values = ['Població','Índex RFD Barcelona = 100'], aggfunc='sum')
pivot_2016_barri.sort_values('Població', ascending=False)
Below what I get:

[image]

When I run the same but for 2015 data, it only recognized one column:
[image]

is there something I am doing wrong or not seeing?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you would show us the 2015 and 2016 data. My guess is that the columns in the 2015 data have different column names (possibly by a very small difference that you didn't notice).

Comment: Thank you! you were actually correct! the difference was impossible to tell so I just copied and pasted the heads of one of the data sets